# R - Extracting number from string with regular expression

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I want to extract a number with decimals from a string with one single expression if possible.

For example transform "2,123.02" to "2123.02" - my current solution is:

```
paste(unlist(str_extract_all("2,123.02","\\(?[0-9.]+\\)?",simplify=F)),collapse="")
```

But what I'm looking for is the expression in str_extract_all to just bind it together as a vector by themself. Is this possible to achieve with an regular expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try replacing the comma by an empty string:

```
gsub(",", "", "2,123.02")
#[1] "2123.02"
```

NB: If you need to replace only commas in between numbers, you can use lookarounds:

```
gsub("(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])", "", "this, this is my number 2,123.02", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "this, this is my number 2123.02"
```

*I edited with `sub` instead of `gsub` in case you have strings with more than one number with a comma. In case you only have one, `sub` is "sufficient".*

NB2: You can call `str_extrac_all` on the result from `gsub`, e.g.:

```
str_extract_all(gsub("(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])", "","first number: 2,123.02, second number: 3,456", perl=T), "\\d+\\.*\\d*", simplify=F)
#[[1]]
#[1] "2123.02" "3456"
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps my understanding of regular expressions.

Comment: Yeah your second line was more what I was looking for, as the strings are more complicated then just removing the "," like in my example. But that did help me, thanks for the extra explanation!

Comment: @CathG you don't need to escape commas in regular expressions, even if `fixed=FALSE`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde indeed :-) I see special characters everywhere (well I guess better escape a non-special character than not escaping a "true" one... ;-) ). Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `extract_numeric` in the **tidyr** package.

```
library(tidyr)
extract_numeric("2,123.02")

[1] 2123.02
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it would work with multiple numbers. The function suppresses anything that is not a digit or a point or a hyphen (minus sign) (`as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]+", "", as.character(x))`)

Comment: @CathG it recognizes minus if that's what you meant?

Comment: @Roman, I mean that if the strings is, for example "2,123.02     2,565", it will end in "weird" thing. like all spaces, text, etc. are suppressed

Comment: @CathG a string such as that would have to be split first, using either `strsplit` or `scan`.

Comment: yes, very likely, I guess the final goal is to get the numbers only, and one by one, to compute something, so there actually won't be a problem in the end